# Confidence rules between applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two different applications on ASP.NET MVC running on the same server.

Both apps works against the same database, but shows different data to users (they are also used by different users).

The fact is that there are some methods on the model of the firstly created app that I'd like to use on the second one, and I don't wanna duplicate the model logic behind those methods.

So for now I'm using a server call from one app to another, that call executes a controller who calls the target method and returns the response.

It works fine, but I don't like to have this controller open to any user calling it. It's not particulary critical information but it seems to me like a serious security problem.

So I've been studying different options.

- I can let that particular controller open to anyone knowing it's out there. Bad.
- I can, somewhat, prompt users for login when the method is called. But the petition is transparent to the user so I'd like to maintain it this way.
- I can elaborate a token-dance between both applications similar to authentication through oAuth protocol to ensure that app1 accepts the login on app2 and executes without a direct login, but this seems like a lot of work for something that should be quite light in the overall project.
- I can let the controller open to anyone, but on execution check the machine from where the petition is coming and throwing an exception if it isn't the same as the running server (both apps runs on same server) instead of returning the result.

At this very moment the idea that likes me the most is this last one. I wonder if anyone out there sees any obvious no-no that I'm not being aware of or can suggest a better approach to this.

Also I'm getting dificulties checking application server and requesting machine. Anyone could throw some light about how could I check this?

Comment: Or, move the code to a common library.

Comment: +1 to @usr, I was just about to write the same.

Comment: Or, extract the methods that are common to both to a service which can be called by both web applications.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your apps should not communicate over HTTP at all. Maybe you can just move the common code to a library project that you can share.

I understand that both apps have full access to the same database. This will work well under that model.

Comment: Exists the possibility that on mid to long term both apps doesn't be located at the same server anymore. In that case wouldn't be a problem to use a common library?

Comment: @Bardo no problem there because both apps will still be able to access the SQL Server database. They don't need to talk to each other at all.